# SpaceX starship landing legs deployment

Tags: spacex-starship

After watching the flight of sn8 the landing legs didn't deploy. What makes them deploy? Velocity?

Comment: It makes sense to deploy them when speed drops below some level so they don't hinder maneuvers, and Musk didn't mention any failures with their deployment, but unless Musk or someone else at SpaceX says something about it, I don't think this is answerable with more than a guess. A picture showing the legs, for reference: https://www.reddit.com/r/SpaceXLounge/comments/jaxfkf/sn8_with_3_raptors_installed/

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff are they these six things? https://i.stack.imgur.com/BskZf.png

Comment: @uhoh yes, they flip out, extend a bit, and bear up against the rim of the skirt when deployed. They're far from the final design, basically telescoping steel struts with holes cut in them so they crumple in a controlled fashion to absorb shock. An earlier version: https://www.teslarati.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Starship-Boca-Chica-080620-NASASpaceflight-bocachicagal-SN5-legs-4-c-2048x1365.jpg

Comment: If its only velocity then the legs should also deploy when it stops going up and start to fall

Comment: Your question might be better worded as "what factors does the software take into account when deciding to deploy the landing legs."    There's certainly a lockout at launch, and probably several others to ensure no premature deployment prior to both low (negative) velocity and ground proximity.